# Select a comma-separated value from one table and use it in where condition in another table using Functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have a table `#table1` with columns `num, codes`:

```
num codes
----------------------------
1   44.00,2724,02.10,50.02  
2   786.59,44.0
```

There is another table `#table2` which removes duplicates from codes column and saves it like this:

```
sno codes
----------
1   44.00
2   2724
3   02.10
4   50.02
5   786.59
```

Now I want to select each comma-separated value in `#table1` and print its appropriate `sno` from `#table2` with a `:` delimiter

For example:

- Result for 1st row in `#table1`: 1:2:3:4
- Result for 2nd row in `#table1`: 5:1

Comment: `select *
from #table1 t1
left join #table2 t2 ON CHARINDEX(t2.codes, t1.codes) > 0`

Comment: BUT IN LAST 2 ROWS INSTEAD OF 5,1 IT SHOWS 1,5

Comment: `order by t1.num, CHARINDEX(t2.codes, t1.codes) asc`

Comment: IT WORKS @artm thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to join `#table1` against `#table2` on the condition that on of the latter's codes be present in the CSV list of the first.  Then, we can rollup using `FOR XML PATH` to obtain a list of matching `sno` values for each number in the first table.

```
SELECT
    t1.codes,
    STUFF((
      SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), t2.sno)
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE ',' + t1.codes + ',' LIKE '%,' + t2.codes + ',%'
      ORDER BY CHARINDEX(t2.codes, t1.codes)
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as list
FROM table1 t1;

codes   list
1       44.00,2724,02.10,50.02  1,2,3,4
2       786.59,44.00            5,1
```

### Demo

I did some conversions here when building the CSV, but you may need to do either more or less, depending on the types of your columns.  In particular, I assumed that all your numerical data is in fact stored as text.  If not, then the above query might not yield the exact matches you want (e.g. `44.00` won't match `44`, even though both are really the same number).

The join condition uses a trick.  Here is an example of what the `LIKE` expression would be, using hard-coded data:

```
WHERE ',44.00,2724,02.10,50.02,' LIKE '%,2724,%'
```

In other words, we search for a number, with commas on both sides, located anywhere in the CSV string in a given record from `#table1`.

Comment: im using sql server 2012 @tim

Comment: @AshwanthKA And...?  My query should absolutely run on SQL Server 2012 with no problem.  Check the demo.

Comment: `WITH table1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num, '44.00,2724,02.10,50.02' AS codes UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '786.59,44.00'
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS sno, '44.00' AS codes UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2724'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '02.10'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '50.02'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '786.59'
)` my codes values may vary on each execution u gave it as default how to change it to get from runtime

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If your data has a problem which precludes the above query from working, then it is your responsibility to fix it.

Comment: in second row of result statement i need the result as 5,1 not 1,5 ?@tim

Comment: @AshwanthKA Add `ORDER BY CHARINDEX(t2.codes, t1.codes)` to the inner subquery.

Comment: i need a function so that data's can be given dynamically

Comment: @AshwanthKA This is a new requirement, and it belongs in a new question, not this one.  Both the answers given here address the query you need to generate your expected output.

Comment: yea you are correct but  as of now i need to pass the values dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive cte if order in your `list` column matters. Here is a sample:

```
with t1 as (
    select
        *
    from
        (values (1, '44.00,2724,02.10,50.02')
            , (2, '786.59,44.0')
        ) t (num, codes)
)
, t2 as (
    select
        *
    from
        (values (1, 44.00)
            , (2, 2724)
            , (3, 02.10)
            , (4, 50.02)
            , (5, 786.59)
        )t (sno, codes)
)
, rcte as (
    select 
        num, codes = cast(codes + ',' as varchar(8000)), charindex(',', codes) ci, list = cast('' as varchar(8000))
    from 
        t1
    union all
    select
        num, cast(stuff(a.codes, 1, ci, '') as varchar(8000)), charindex(',', stuff(a.codes, 1, ci, '')), cast(concat(a.list, ':', b.sno) as varchar(8000))
    from
        rcte a
        join t2 b on substring(a.codes, 1, ci - 1) = b.codes
    where
        len(a.codes) > 0
)
select
    num, list = stuff(list, 1, 1, '')
from
    rcte
where
    ci = 0
order by num
```

Output:

```
num       list
--------------
1         1:2:3:4
2         5:1
```

Comment: i need this without using with statement

Comment: It is a `recursive CTE`. You can't use it without `with` statement. In that case you need to use @Tim Biegeleisen solution

Comment: i need a function so that data's can be sent dynamically